# How to add document with map data to firestore using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have a document like below

[image]

But when i use the following code to add new document containing map it adds the data like the one shown in below picture

```
 Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(some_docID).updateData({
      'map1.key1': 'value1',
      'map1.key2': 'value2'
    });
```

Even if I use setData it still adds data as below, not as I wanted which is in the above picture.

[image]

Also one thing is that if the document is already present and it has at least one map field then if I use the above code it adds the data as map only. the problem is only when I want to create new document with map values. If anyone could suggest a solution would be great help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is are several differences between [`document.updateData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) and [`document.setData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) which need to be understood:

Firstly, you cannot *create* a document using `updateData`. The document must be created before calling `updateData` or the call will fail. This might have been the source of your problems.

## Create a document with nested data

You must use `document.setData`. `setData` requires that you specify your data in "nested" format, where fields are not "flattened" or "dot-delimited".

So for your example:

```dart
 Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(some_docID).setData({
      'map1': {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
      }});
```

## Update a document with nested data

If you want to guarantee that a document was previously created, then you should use `document.updateData` (which as mentioned before, will fail if `document` was not previously created).

`updateData` requires that nested fields be specified in "dot-delimited" fashion.

So for your example:

```
updateData({
      'map1.key1': 'value1',
      'map1.key2': 'value2',
});
```

### Accidentally overwriting fields with nested fields in `updateData`

If you pass data in nested format to `updateData`, it will assume that you wish to *fully* replace the value of a key with the subsequent data.

For example, if your document has data `{'a': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}` and you run `updateData({'a': {'b': 4}})` the document will *not* just replace `a.b` with `4`, but will also delete the `c` field, since it was not included in the `a` value passed to `updataData`.

To only fields explicitly, use the dot-delimited format or `setData(data, merge: true)` (see below).

### Updating data using `setData`

Note: You can also still use `setData` to update data on a document. Still, the format required is "nested" and not dot-delimited.

If you wish to only update certain fields of `document` explicitly, then pass `merge: true` to `setData`.

Comment: I understand now... thank your for your detailed explanation... was really helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the data like this:

```
 Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(some_docID).updateData({
    "map1" : {
      "key1" : "value1",
      "key2" : "value2"
    }
    });
```

This will create a map in the database.

Comment: This answer is misleading in 2 ways. First, the question asks how to *add* a document, which means create. `updateData` will fail if the document was not previously created.

Second, if there was a `map1.key3` field in the document, your approach would delete that field. Likely the intent of the question is to only update `map1.key1` and `map2.key2` and leave all other fields untouched.

Please see my answer for more details